# How to call one activity multiple times based on from which the activity has been called?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, bundle

I have one activity which is common for all other activities. I want to call this activity and want to set some conditions based on from which activity it has been called. I thought of bundle for this. How can I call a condition based on bundle value? I have another activity in between. I am not calling the activity directly. So how can we pass data by using bundle?

```
  txt_from.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PickLocationActivity.class);
            GoSendData.instance.addressType = 0;
            i.putExtra("type",1);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

From this I am calling second activity.

In common activity I have a view I am calling the activity back from this. The activity from which it has been called , it should be called back from this view.

```
 useLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            activityType = extras.getInt("type");

            if(activityType==0) {

                intent = new Intent(ChooseFromMapActivity.this, GoSend.class);

                startActivity(intent);
            }

            if(activityType == 1)
            {
                intent = new Intent(ChooseFromMapActivity.this, GoRideActivity.class);

                startActivity(intent);
            }

        }
    });
```

How to achieve this...?

How can I do this with shared preferences?

Comment: what problem you are facing ?

Comment: Here I am getting null pointer for a bundle. Is it the right way to access data from bundle?

Comment: So you want to know from which activity you came to your common activity,right?

Comment: yes and want to go back to the same activity. @Parag Kadam

Comment: so you mean, Activity1-->CommonActivity---->Activity1 ... ? am i correct.?

Comment: activity1 --> activity 2---> activity 3--->activity 1

Comment: so activity 3 is the common activity correct. ?

Comment: yes 3rd is common..@ Ragu Swaminathan

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
```

to

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code

Activity_1. : This will send the data to the Common Activity.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Activity_1.this, CommonActivity.class);
i.putExtra("type",1);
startActivity(i);
```

Activity_2. : This will send the data to the Common Activity.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Activity_2.this, CommonActivity.class);
i.putExtra("type",2);
startActivity(i);
```

Then on your Common Activity write this code in the onCreate function.

```
int receivedValue = getIntent().getIntExtra("type", 0);
// here 0 is the default value when there is no data in the particular key.
```

now you can check the condition like this

```
if(receivedValue==1)
{
// do something here
}

if(receivedValue==2)
{
// do something here
}
```

This will definitely work for you. Try it..!!
Happy coding.

Comment: Unable to call back activity.. Note-- I have another activity in between.

Answer (score 0):

`Activity1`,

```
txt_from.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PickLocationActivity.class);
            GoSendData.instance.addressType = 0;
            i.putExtra("type",1);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

`Activity2`,

```
txt_from.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PickLocationActivity.class);
            GoSendData.instance.addressType = 0;
            i.putExtra("type",2);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

`Common Activity`

```
useLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = getIntent();
            int type = i.getInt("type");

            if(type==1) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(ChooseFromMapActivity.this, Activity1.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            if(type == 2)
            {
               Intent intent = new Intent(ChooseFromMapActivity.this, Activity2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: I have one more activity in between..How can I do this with shared preferences? @parag kadam

Comment: Then you can send the `type` to the activity that comes in between using `intent`, and then again using `intent` send the `type` to the final activity. If you want to persist the `type` (in case you close your app in the between) then you can use `shared preference` if persistence is required in your case.